# why use the Package java.nio.file.Path without importing it?

Tags: java, package, java.nio.file

i have the two classes :

```
public class ScriptTests {

    private final java.nio.file.Path test_file;
   // ...
}

public class TestD {
public static void main(String args[]) {
     java.nio.file.Path test_file= Paths.get(args[0]);
     // ....
}
}
```

Those classes are used to test code I wrote. My question is why did they always use this Package  with its full name? Why not simply use `import` at the start and then use a simpler name like they did in all the other Packages?

For example : `import java.io.*;`

I am asking because it just seemed weird. I think there is probably a reason!

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can use the "import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;" and remove all the declaration of the packages and everything compiles

Comment: but why when in the files that are testing the code they use the full name each time , i know they could have used import , but why not , there is a reson for that i am sure

Comment: You would have to ask the person who wrote the code. Maybe they were trying to avoid a class name collision (i.e. there is also some other `Path` class being used from some other package, not shown in your code - unlikely, but possible). Or maybe they should have used an import, like you would have expected.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can't read the mind of the person who wrote the code.

Comment: i asked if there was a known reason for that ! no one asked you to read minds , just say there is no known reason :)

Comment: Known by who?  The person who wrote the code *may* have had a reason.  It *may* have been a valid reason.  It may *still* be a valid reason.  We simply cannot know ... without seeing the complete change history for the relevant files.  (For example, there might have been a `Path` class in the same package as `TestD` that was used without qualification in `TestD`.)

Comment: The point is **nobody** here can **know** the reason without that information.  You basically asked an unanswerable question.  If you asked a slightly different question, it would have been answerable.

Comment: actually yes there is another class in thre code called public interface Path<N, P extends Path<N,P>>
   extends Iterable<N>, Comparable<Path<?,?>>  { maybe thats the reason ?

Comment: My first guess would be there is (or was) another class named Path somewhere in the app’s history, so someone wrote it like that to handle that case. And since then it’s either been copy pasted or followed because they didn’t realise why it was used in the other case. That or whoever wrote it didn’t have a good IDE that fills in imports for you, and they copied the code from a stack overflow answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the entire declaration of the class using the package when you need to use two classes of different packages for example if you need to use both classes Date in one method. If you don't need to use two or more classes with the same name but with different packages is a good practice to use the import to become the code more readable.

**Example**

```
package com.stackoverflow.question;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        
        System.out.println(sqlDate);
        System.out.println(utilDate);
        System.out.println(timestamp);
    }
}
```

**Note**: It's a bad practice to import all the classes of one particular package ("**import java.sql.***"), just import the classes that you need.